# Storage Virtualization/Replication for KVM Live Migration on 2 Nodes

Tags: kvm-virtualization, storage, replication

at the moment I'm doing some researching on Virtualization on Linux.
My target scenarion would be a 2 Node "Cluster" with replicated storage over IP. (a little Like Windows HCI)

I already took a look at Open-Stacks but thats a little oversized and putting it all together feels  like a 1000 Parts Puzzle :)

So going back to the Basics looking at KVM i saw that you can do Live Migration If you have a shared storage.

So now to the question: Is there an easy way to implement a Storage Replication for that Usecase in Linux?

I would be very tankful if someone can Point me in the right direction.

Comment: Look at DRDB, it is linux service for storage replication

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with GlusterFS:

https://blog.intelligentbee.com/2017/09/25/glusterfs-replicate-volume-two-nodes/

So basically, you'll use the bricks with GlusterFS and then install KVM on top (guests disks) so you can do live migration between the two nodes seamlessly.